# Questions about proving Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem

Tags: lie-algebras

I am reading the book **Introduction to Lie Algebras** by Karin Erdmann and Mark J. Wildon. In a short chapter of universal enveloping Lie algebra, they shortly mentioned the **PBW**-basis without proving it.

I wonder is there any comprehensive and detailed proof of the theorem?

Could anyone give me some reference books or articles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is proved in detail in [Humphrey's "Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory"](https://books.google.com/books?id=TeMlBQAAQBAJ) in section 17.4 (appropriately named Proof of PBW Theorem).